# write the following code (Assembly)

Tags: assembly

This question taken from a book assembly language programming
Place the top of the stack into AX, without changing the contents of stack.
How is it possible without using push and pop?

Comment: Assuming  x86, in AT&T style GAS syntax: movl (%esp), %eax    or rather movw (%esp), %ax if you want 16bit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like Intel assembly.

```
mov ax, sp; moves the address of the top of the stack into ax.
mov ax, [sp]; moves the contents of the top of the stack into ax.
```

Comment: @seproland I've reverted your edit. While you're right that `[sp]` isn't a legal addressing mode, changing to `[esp]` makes it inconsistent with the rest of the post. The entire post should be fixed, but its not clear if the original poster needs a 16-bit or 32-bit solution.

Comment: I would have provided a 16-bit answer similar to `mov bp, sp`
`mov ax, [bp]` as one method for 16-bit code.

Comment: The question is actually 16-bit specific from page 158 of `Assembly-Language-Programming-Organization-of-the-IBM-PC-1992`. This version of the book was 8086. There was another revision of the book later on that covered the 386, but the exercises aren't the same. My guess is that this question was for 16-bit